# How to write static code analyzer for .net

Tags: vb.net, code-analysis

I am interested in writing static code analyzer for vb.net to see if it conforms to my company standard coding guidelines. Please advise from where i have to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FXCop](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70294) is a good start for coding problems/mistakes, [StyleCop](http://blogs.msdn.com/sourceanalysis/) is good for coding style (obviously), but if neither of those two work then you then you can either write a parser yourself or use the [VBCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.vbcodeprovider.aspx) class in the .Net Framework

Answer (score 16):

Rather than write your own static code analyzer, I recommend you use [FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476(VS.80).aspx): and instead, write custom FxCop rules for your needs. It'll save you a lot of time.
http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you use Mono's Gendarme. It's a very nice tool, with plenty of built in rules. It also generates nice HTML reports.

Answer (score 2):

if you need mroe architectural insight use NDepend. This tool does not stop to amaze me. It can do soo much more than FxCop. It's commercial though, but has a free trial version

Answer (score 0):

Start with FxCop.  If you can't do what you're trying there, try something like NStatic or NDepend.

Answer (score 0):

The best options are to use FxCop or StyleCop and write custom rules if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Use FxCop, this isn't a project you want to undertake personally. The parsing/lexical rules involved and the possible catches would be insane. The only way I could imagine doing it while retaining a modicum of sanity would be to use Lisp thanks to the extreme amount of expressiveness, but again, best to use FxCop.

If you must write a custom in-house tool for some (dogmatic?) reason, I'd recommend writing a Lisp program that does only basic rules-checking. Don't try to make it comprehensive, we're talking the kind of frontier that AI researchers are dealing with in terms of the parsing capabilities of a piece of software.

Just use Lisp to find the possible obvious offenders, or just at catching whatever it ends up being good at catching in terms of non-compliant code, then subject it to a brief human eye scan. I highly recommend abusing macros if you do use Lisp to write the parser.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with one of the posters that it would be a quite difficult taks, but rather than with Lisp I'd start with F#, just like Microsoft did for their 3rd party windows drivers analysis tool:

http://arstechnica.com/journals/microsoft.ars/2005/11/10/1796

F# shares Lisp's expressiveness (ok, almost) and works on CLR just like VB.NET, which would make the whole thing easier.